# Understanding relative paths

Tags: php, apache, path, dir

I'm having some trouble with understanding the meaning of this snippet. I know that __ DIR __ refers to my absolute path, in my case /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

```
__ DIR __.'/../app'
```

Where is this path looking for the folder /app?

thx,

Comment: `/Applications/MAMP/app`

Comment: the ../ means go up one level in the folder structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This path means:

```
/Applications/MAMP/app
```

`..` is the directory above. So he enters htdocs, enters the parentdirectory (which is MAMP) and then the directory app.

And for the knowledge: Should you ever see `.`, this means current directory. For example:

```
C:/Users/Admin/.
```

means exactly:

```
C:/Users/Admin/.
```

`..` would mean:

```
C:/Users/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is looking for /app under /Applications/MAMP/

```
__ DIR __.'/../app'
____________^
```

That's because you have the .. which means parent directory.